# Need to clip raster based on field name in ArcGIS 9.3

Tags: raster, arcgis-9.3

Is there a way around for me to batch clip a raster using a field name to create output a raster layer ? Much like using Split tool but it is for a vector. How about that for the raster side ?

Going to do that for slope and elevation by 24k quad. I am using ArcGIS 9.3.1 and I am aware that the 10 has a raster split.

Comment: Added a link to a tool. You might want to test if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Hawth's Analysis Tool's for ArcGIS. It has a [Clip Raster By Polygon Tools](http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/cliprasterbypolys.php).

[image]

**Recipe:**

1. Create a polygon from your raster. Select it as the polygon layer under **Input**.
2. Pick the field name that you want to use as the basis for the clip.
3. Select the original layer as the raster layer.
4. Choose an output directory.

A warning from the website though:

> this tool uses standard Spatial Analyst functionality and is therefore
>   rather slow

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I really understand what you want to do. But you can make a shapefile and use that as a mask. I hope "Extract by mask" (in spatial analyst) should work.

Cheers
N

Comment: Exactly I am awared of that, but I had to do by indivdiually. How about a batch or model builder ?