# Is there a Raster Equivalent of the Split tool?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, splitting

I have the DEM of a State in ERDAS Imagine (.img) format. I have a shapefile containing the counties of that state.

I want to split the whole raster into DEMs of the individual counties. The counties are irregular polygons. So this isn't as easy as splitting the Raster into tiles.

How do I split a raster with a vector polygon shapefile?

I am looking for what is basically the Raster equivalent of the [Split tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Split/000800000006000000/).

I tried using [Clip tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Clip/00170000009n000000/), and the [Extract by mask](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Extract_by_Mask/009z0000002n000000/) tool, but both of them are unhelpful since they work only on single polygons.

I have looked at the answer given here: [Need to clip raster based on field name in ArcGIS 9.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15658/need-to-clip-raster-based-on-field-name-in-arcgis-9-3)
, but Hawth Tools aren't available for ArcGIS 10.0

I have ArcGIS 10.0+ Spatial Analyst Extension, and QGIS 1.8. A solution in either will be acceptable.

Comment: The raster equivalent of the split tool is the [Split Raster Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Split_Raster/00170000009v000000/)

Comment: @danb: The Split raster tool is not equivalent; It can only split the raster into tiles, and not in any arbitrary polygons.

Comment: a python answer is here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37325/clipping-raster-by-multiple-datasets-or-polygons

Comment: ...and a toolbox ready python answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37325/clipping-raster-by-multiple-datasets-or-polygons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This model builder workflow will extract a section of the DEM for each county polygon

[image]

- Set the **Group by Field** variable to be County Name
- Set the model processing extent to be the same as **County**

Comment: Thanks! I basically created a script which does basically the same thing.

Comment: Regarding the model above, how does this give multiple outputs? I always get only one output, one raster instead of many.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script to loop through your polygons and clip the raster to that.  But the following might be quicker.

Hawth's tools has been replaced by the [Geospatial Modelling Environment](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/index.htm) (GME).  You will need to have [the R program](http://www.r-project.org/) installed in order to run the GME.  Also, GME doesn't seem to work yet in ArcGIS 10.2.

The tool you want is the [Clip Raster by Polygons](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/cliprasterbypolys.htm) tool.

The description of the tool is:

> This tool clips an input raster using the polygons in a polygon data
>   source. The command cycles through each polygon, clips the raster if
>   there is overlap, and writes one new raster image per polygon. The
>   extent of the new raster is the intersection of the extent of the
>   polygon and the extent of the raster.
>
> This tool is designed to work with these three raster formats: grids,
>   TIFF/GeoTIFF, and ERDAS Imagine rasters. Note that not all raster
>   formats support all datatypes. When you are clipping a raster it is
>   recommended you consider two strategies to avoid these pixel data type
>   problems: 1) ensure the output format matches the input format, or 2)
>   always use the Imagine img format as the output format as this
>   supports all the data types. The output format is specified by adding
>   the appropriate file extension to the file name. No extension is
>   interpreted as the grid format, the '.tif' extension is the GeoTIFF
>   format, and the '.img' extension is the Imagine format.
>
> Note that all clips will preserve the cell alignment of the input
>   raster (no shifting of pixels will occur at all). However, the display
>   properties of the input raster are not transferred to the output
>   raster, so if you are clipping digital photos or satellite images you
>   should expect the appearance of the clipped images to differ from that
>   of the original image.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS, 
`RASTER|EXTRACTION|CLIPPER` with the clipping mode set to `Mask Layer`
will do it if I understand your question correctly.